# C++ Calling set function from another class in file reader

Tags: c++, file, constructor

I'm pretty much a C++ newbie at this point. I'm more experienced with Java so I'm really not used to the syntax specifications of C++.

With this being said, I'm trying to make a small application that will read a .txt file (line by line) and, based on how many commas each line has, it will send the respective parameters to a temporary t1 or t2 variable, being t1 of Type1 and t2 of Type2.

Type1 and Type2 are subclasses of Maintype, and subsequently inherit a 'description' string from this 'Maintype'. Both Type1 and Type2 have their set() methods for their respective parameters (setName, setSize, etc) but I can't get this thing to work. This is my progress so far, I've got it commented for ease of understanding:

```
void Test::readFile(string f)
{
    int c = 0;
    int com = 0;
    fstream file;
    file.open(f);
    string line;
    stringstream ss(line);
    if (!file)
        cout << "File not found!" << endl;
    while (!file.eof())
    {
        c = 0;
        getline(file, line, '\n');
        if (line.size() > 0)
        {
            com = count(line.begin(), line.end(), ','); // Count commas         
            Type1 t1(); // Temporary t1
            Type2 t2(); // Temporary t2
            String description;
            std::string token;
            while (std::getline(ss, token, ','))
            { // Might change this while later if necessary
                if (c == 0)
                { // First parameter is description
                    description = token;
                    c++;
                }
                else if (com > 1)
                { // If more than one comma
                    t1.setDesc(description);
                    t1.setName(token);
                    // Next token
                    t1.setSize( /*convert token string to int*/ );
                    // ---End reading string
                    // ---Send t1 to a list of Maintypes
                }
                else
                { // Local natural
                    t2.setDesc(description);
                    t2.setTime( /*convert token string to int*/ );
                    // ---End reading string
                    // ---Sent t2 to a list of Maintypes

                }

            }
        }
        file.close();
    }
}
```

I'm pretty sure I'm not doing the setDesc etc correctly, it says 'expression must have class type'. Now I know this isn't Java, but I'm really not used to this. Also, regarding the method itself, am I in the correct way to implement a file reading solution?

Many thanks!

Comment: `Type1 t1();` and `Type2 t2();` are not varible declarations, they're function declarations.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

these lines

```
Type1 t1(); //not a Temporary t1
Type2 t2(); //not a Temporary t2
```

don't do what you think: they declare functions `t1()` and `t2()` taking no arguments and returning `Type1` and `Type2`, respectively. This is also known as C++ most vexing parse ...

Simply omit the `()`

```
Type1 t1; //Temporary t1
Type2 t2; //Temporary t2
```

and it does what you want. In C++11, you can also use `{}`:

```
Type1 t1{}; //Temporary t1
Type2 t2{}; //Temporary t2
```

Comment: Thank you for pointing this out. That was incredibly retarded of me. I'm not sure why I did that. I suppose it should be working now, I'm going to do the necessary changes to my file reader method and see how it works. Many thanks :)

Comment: It was not *incredibly retarded* -- it has happened many a times to experienced programmers ...

Comment: I do suppose so! I have another question, as you might be able to see, I want to send these t1's and t2's to lists. In short, what is the most effective/normal way to declare two empty lists, one for each type of data, in this Test.h file? I'm pretty much just looking (I think) for something the likes of list<Type1> list1 that will allow me to do list1.push_back(/*file_data*/) or something.